# Auto logon-Intune joined devices-Only need google chrome on startup on the pc

Tags: authentication, auto, kiosk-mode, intune, splunk-dashboard

I have requirement:Need to setup an Intune joined PC to Auto logon with O365 account(no license).
Chrome should open automatically for Splunk Dashboards(Edge doesn't have Splunk extension).

1. Currently Excluded from all the policies, tried setting up the Kiosk Multi app but Auto logon not working.
2. Removed EAS key from Registry keys, setup Autologon from Sysinternal tools which is working fine till restart, but after restart the EAS key is recreating and blocking the Autologon.

Can you please guide me if you have setup Autologin for Windows 11-Intune joined PCs to use chrome.

Ven